# Convert & symbol in scss to less

Tags: css, sass, less

I have to convert some SCSS files to LESS.  For most part it is just case of changing $ with @ but there are style that use the scss parent selector `&` that I don't know how to convert.

Here is example

```
  // Sidebar
  .sidebar {
    .block {
      &.newsletter {
        .btn {
          &:before {
            background: transparent;
          }
        }
      }
      &.filter {
        ol {
          li {
            a {
              color: @blue;

              &:before {
                display: none;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      .filter-options-title, .block-title {
        color: #444;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        font-size: 12px;

        &:after {
          color: #666;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

How would I replace out those parent selectors to make it the same generated CSS?

Comment: Use an online converter like https://sass2css.herokuapp.com/?

Comment: i need to convert to LESS

Comment: Allright, convert above to `css` with the link i gave in my previous comment. Then convert the output `css` to `less` with this link https://www.css2less.net/

Comment: Well, why not sending you the output directly ;) https://pastebin.com/TC16H0W9

Comment: Less and SCSS have really similar syntax, https://css-tricks.com/sass-vs-less/ Your code is basically already right ! ;)

Comment: Instead of converting to LESS, why not just convert to CSS? Then you wouldn't have to worry about such arcane syntax details and could simplify your pipeline and speed up your build.

Comment: I'm agree with Lissy & = &

Answer (score 5):

### The `&` parent selector is actually the same syntax in Less and SCSS!

---

From the [Less Documentation on Parent Selectors](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature):

> The `&` operator
>   represents the parent selectors of a nested rule and is most commonly
>   used when applying a modifying class or pseudo-class to an existing
>   selector

In comparison, here's the SASS/ SCSS documentation on parent selectors for pseudo classes: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Selector/Pseudo.html

---

So in the case of your code, it would be:

**SCSS**

```
$blue: blue;

   .sidebar {
    .block {
      &.newsletter {
        .btn {
          &:before {
            background: transparent;
          }
        }
      }
      &.filter {
        ol li a {
              color: $blue;
               &:before {
                display: none;
              }
        }
      }
      .filter-options-title, .block-title {
        color: #444;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        font-size: 12px;

        &:after {
          color: #666;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

*(try compiling/ validating here: https://www.sassmeister.com/)*

**LESS**

```
@blue: blue;

   .sidebar {
    .block {
      &.newsletter {
        .btn {
          &:before {
            background: transparent;
          }
        }
      }
      &.filter {
        ol li a {
              color: @blue;
               &:before {
                display: none;
              }
        }
      }
      .filter-options-title, .block-title {
        color: #444;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        font-size: 12px;

        &:after {
          color: #666;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

*(try compiling/ validating here: http://winless.org/online-less-compiler)*

---

As well as the official documentation, this article on CSS Tricks is helpful too: https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand

Hope that helps :)